# ¿Como especificar el puerto de Selenium Firefox WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Estoy teniendo el siguiente error con Selenium Firefox Webdriver

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   Unable to bind  to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms  Build info:
>   version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:32:46'
>   System info: host: '***',  ip: '192.168.100.1', os.name: 'Windows',
>   os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_101' Driver
>   info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver at
>   org.openqa.selenium.internal.SocketLock.lock(SocketLock.java:99) at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:80)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:271)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:119)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:218)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:211)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:124)

Este problema surge cuando estoy ejecutando mi programa por segunda vez (tengo en ejecución alguna prueba con el webdriver de firefox).

¿Es posible usar el webdriver firefox desde 2 programas java?
¿Tengo que modificar el puerto?¿Como lo hago?

Answer (score 0):

Despues de un poco Google-fu he encontrado varios hilos respecto al tema:

https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4790

https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/7272

Antes de nada actualizate todo a las versiones mas modernas si puedes.

Te hago un resumen de posibles soluciones que comentan en los links:

> 1. Aumenta el timeout(por defecto a 45 segundos) así:

```
FirefoxProfileffProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary();
ffBinary.setTimeout(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(180));
WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary, ffProfile);
```

> 2. Cambia el puerto (por defecto 7054):

```
FirefoxProfileffProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
ffProfile.setPreference(FirefoxProfile.PORT_PREFERENCE, aCustomPort);
```

> 3. Sincroniza cualquier creación del webServer de firefox

La idea es poner un sincronize al código que devuelve el WebDriver.